# Java EE security/programatic login: How does one make the authentication "stick" in the session?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

Consider this code block:

```
        HttpServletRequest request = Faces.getRequest();
        if (request.getRemoteUser() == null) {
            try {
                request.login(userName, password);
                request.getSession().invalidate();
                request.getSession(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("login() failed with exception", e);
                Messages.addWarn(null, "Authentication Failed");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("login() user is already authenticated");
        }
```

Lets say your authentication is successful. If the user refreshes the page and goes through this method again, the `log.debug("login() user is already authenticated");` line is not reached.

We want to log the user in programmatically then have that user be associated with the session (like how spring and shiro work). How do you do this?

Our `web.xml`:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>SomeRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Everything</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is not reached, because you are destroying the session in the very next line, logging you out again:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Comment: I also realized that this is kind of "pointless" to do. Tomcat has had builtin session fixation protection for awhile: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/04/25/session-fixation-protection  As long as you're not doing anything stupid, there's not real reason to do this anymore